# How do I update a Mongo document after inserting it?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

Let's say I insert the document.

```
post = { some dictionary }
mongo_id = mycollection.insert(post)
```

Now, let's say I want to add a field and update it. How do I do that? This doesn't seem to work.....

```
post = mycollection.find_one({"_id":mongo_id}) 
post['newfield'] = "abc"
mycollection.save(post)
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

In pymongo you can update with:

```
mycollection.update({'_id':mongo_id}, {"$set": post}, upsert=False)
```

Upsert parameter will insert instead of updating if the post is not found in the database.
Documentation is available at [mongodb site](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating).

**UPDATE** For version > 3 use `update_one` instead of `update`:

```
mycollection.update_one({'_id':mongo_id}, {"$set": post}, upsert=False)
```

Comment: @Elliott - what is the other alternative?

Answer (score 37):

```
mycollection.find_one_and_update({"_id": mongo_id}, 
                                 {"$set": {"newfield": "abc"}})
```

should work splendidly for you. If there is no document of id `mongo_id`, it will fail, unless you also use `upsert=True`. This returns the old document by default. To get the new one, pass `return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER`. All parameters are described in [the API](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update).

The method was introduced for MongoDB 3.0. It was extended for 3.2, 3.4, and 3.6.

Comment: It also works if you sub "_id" for another field like "username" fyi

Comment: @Chris When you say "current pymongo", those of us from the future may not have the same version. It's nice to be specific.

Comment: @Mnebuerquo this is an excellent point I wouldnt have seen otherwise. Will do in future posts, thx.

Comment: @Chris The edit helps a lot. Thanks! And thanks from future-me when I forget this and have to look it up again!

Answer (score 22):

I will use `collection.save(the_changed_dict)` this way. I've just tested this, and it still works for me. The following is quoted directly from `pymongo doc.`:

`save(to_save[, manipulate=True[, safe=False[, **kwargs]]])`

> Save a document in this collection.
>
> If to_save already has an "_id" then 
>   an update() (upsert) operation is performed and 
>   any existing document with that "_id" is
>   overwritten. Otherwise an insert() operation is performed. In this
>   case if manipulate is True an "_id" will be added to to_save and this
>   method returns the "_id" of the saved document. If manipulate is False
>   the "_id" will be added by the server but this method will return
>   None.

Answer (score 13):

According to the latest documentation about PyMongo titled [Insert a Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/python/insert/#insert-a-document) (insert is deprecated) and following defensive approach, you should insert and update as follows:

```
result = mycollection.insert_one(post)
post = mycollection.find_one({'_id': result.inserted_id})

if post is not None:
    post['newfield'] = "abc"
    mycollection.save(post)
```

Answer (score 11):

This is an old question, but I stumbled onto this when looking for the answer so I wanted to give the update to the answer for reference.

The methods `save` and `update` are deprecated.

> save(to_save, manipulate=True, check_keys=True, **kwargs)¶ Save a
>   document in this collection.
>
> DEPRECATED - Use insert_one() or replace_one() instead.
>
> Changed in version 3.0: Removed the safe parameter. Pass w=0 for
>   unacknowledged write operations.
>
> update(spec, document, upsert=False, manipulate=False, multi=False,
>   check_keys=True, **kwargs) Update a document(s) in this collection.
>
> DEPRECATED - Use replace_one(), update_one(), or update_many()
>   instead.
>
> Changed in version 3.0: Removed the safe parameter. Pass w=0 for
>   unacknowledged write operations.

in the OPs particular case, it's better to use [`replace_one`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.replace_one).