# How to update values using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I've a mongodb collection in this form:

```
{id=ObjectId(....),key={dictionary of values}}
where dictionary of values is {'a':'1','b':'2'.....}
```

Let dictionary of values be `'d'`.
I need to update the values of the key in the `'d'`.
i.e I want to change `'a':'1'` to `'a':'2'`
How can do I this in pymongo?

Code goes something like this:

```
productData is a collection in mongoDB
for p in productData.find():
     for k,v in p.iteritems():
         value=v['a']
         value=value+1
         v['a']=value
```

Now reflect the new value in the productData.

This is what I've tried and it introduces a new key-value pair instead of updating the

```
for p in productData.find():
    for k,v in p.iteritems():
         value=v['a']
         value=value+1
         v['a']=value
         productData.update({'_id':mongoId},{"$set":{'d.a':'100'}},upsert=False)
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372797/how-do-i-update-a-mongo-document-after-inserting-it

Comment: Does the same thing apply for update of an existing field?

Comment: Pretty sure it does, yes.  Try it and see what happens.

Comment: For one you should be doing "for k,v in p['d'].iteritems()" - also, Mark's answer below does work without creating a new key/value pair.  You should post more code so we can see what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can use the $set syntax if you want to set the value of a document to an arbitrary value. This will either update the value if the attribute already exists on the document or create it if it doesn't. If you need to set a single value in a dictionary like you describe, you can use the dot notation to access child values.

If p is the object retrieved:

```
existing = p['d']['a']
```

***For pymongo versions < 3.0***

```
db.ProductData.update({
  '_id': p['_id']
},{
  '$set': {
    'd.a': existing + 1
  }
}, upsert=False, multi=False)
```

***For pymongo versions >= 3.0***

```
db.ProductData.update_one({
  '_id': p['_id']
},{
  '$set': {
    'd.a': existing + 1
  }
}, upsert=False)
```

However if you just need to increment the value, this approach could introduce issues when multiple requests could be running concurrently. Instead you should use the $inc syntax:

***For pymongo versions < 3.0:***

```
db.ProductData.update({
  '_id': p['_id']
},{
  '$inc': {
    'd.a': 1
  }
}, upsert=False, multi=False)
```

***For pymongo versions >= 3.0:***

```
db.ProductData.update_one({
  '_id': p['_id']
},{
  '$inc': {
    'd.a': 1
  }
}, upsert=False)
```

This ensures your increments will always happen.

Comment: This introduces a new key-value pair

Comment: There are missing `}` in both update statements at the `$set` and `$inc` part.

Comment: `$set` should be quoted: `'$set'`. Otherwise it throws syntax error.

Answer (score 9):

With my pymongo version: 3.2.2 I had do the following

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client.mydbname

db.ProductData.update_one({
  '_id': ObjectId(p['_id']['$oid'])
},{
  '$set': {
    'd.a': existing + 1
  }
}, upsert=False)
```

Comment: faced with  TypeError
Exception Value: 
Object of type 'ObjectId' is not JSON serializable on django1.11

Comment: This looks kind of awesome, but I don't think it works.  in the '$set', `existing + 1` is not a lambda, so it will use whatver `existing` variable is in scope (or raise an exception if there is none), rather than using the actual existing value in the field.

Answer (score 2):

Something I did recently, hope it helps. I have a list of dictionaries and wanted to add a value to some existing documents.

```py
for item in my_list:
    my_collection.update({"_id" : item[key] }, {"$set" : {"New_col_name" :item[value]}})
```

Comment: `DeprecationWarning: update is deprecated. Use replace_one, update_one or update_many instead.`

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the operators (e.g., `$set`) should be in quotes:

```
db.ProductData.update(
    {'fromAddress': 'http://localhost:7000/'},
    {'$set': {'fromAddress': 'http://localhost:5000/'}},
    {'multi': True}
)
```