# MongoDB not updating field in Python

Tags: python, mongodb

```
def add_questions(email, classroom, questions):
   print(classroom + "  " + str(questions))
   db.sessions.update_one({ #questions added to session coming up.
       "email": email,
        "status": "on",
        "classroom": classroom
    }, {
        "$set": {
            "questions": questions
        }
    })
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxxbL.png

That is the structure (in the image).

But it isn't updating? I want to replace the old questions array (as you see in the image) to the new one from my params.

Comment: Are you sure that the document with {"email": email,  "status": "on",  "classroom": classroom} exists?

Comment: yeah, the image @OleksandrKaleniuk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update values using pymongo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710770/how-to-update-values-using-pymongo)

Comment: There is class into collection, I can't see classroom, try change classroom to class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'classroom' property in the provided document. So the query should look like:

```
   db.sessions.update_one({
       "email": email,
        "status": "on",
        "class": classroom
    }, {
        "$set": {
            "questions": questions
        }
    })
```