# How do I update a MongoDB collection using the ObjectId _id?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, updates

I am trying to update a mongodb collection using python.
I am trying to update the collection using the ObjectId but it is not working.

```
result = myCollection.update_one(
    {_id:"53298scc1c29d0s036c"},
    {
        "$set": {
            "lname":"Jones"
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update values using pymongo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13710770/how-to-update-values-using-pymongo)

Comment: Hi! It would be easier to answer your question with a bit more detail. e.g. are there any errors? What output are you getting vs what are you expecting? "It is not working" doesn't really help people help you. I would recommend reading [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
from bson import ObjectId

result = myCollection.update_one(
{"_id": ObjectId("53298scc1c29d0s036c")},
{
    "$set": {
        "lname":"Jones"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cast your `_id` value to be `ObjectId` type.

```
from bson import ObjectId

result = myCollection.update_one(
{_id: ObjectId("53298scc1c29d0s036c")},
{
    "$set": {
        "lname":"Jones"
    }
})
```

Comment: Put quotes around _id and it worked.  "_id":    thank you