# Update field instead of add to a field pymongo

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

Whenever I try to update a field, it ends up adding the number to the field instead of replacing it. For example:

```py
db.test.update_one({"_id": 0}, {'$inc': {"time": 2}})
```

If there were already 1 in the field time, the field time would update to 3 instead of 2. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I update a Mongo document after inserting it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372797/how-do-i-update-a-mongo-document-after-inserting-it)

Comment: I tried it, but it still just adds to the field.

Comment: max meinz : You might be missing something, `$set` will overwrite existing value doesn't increment it !!

Comment: It doesn't matter with type of input value..

Comment: post = {"coins":1}
collection.update_one({'_id':1}, {"$set": post}, upsert=False) does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
collection = client.testdb.test

print(collection.find_one())    # 'time': 1

collection.update_one( { '_id': 0 }, { '$set': { 'time': 3 } } )
print(collection.find_one())    #  'time': 4

collection.update_one( { '_id': 0 }, { '$inc': { 'time': 1 } } )
print(collection.find_one())    #  'time': 5
```

MongoDB document data can be updated with the `update_one` method. You can use different [update operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/index.html) for different update operations, e.g., `$set`, `$inc`, `$unset`, etc.

- `$inc` Increments the value of the field by the specified amount.
- `$set` Sets the value of a field in a document.

You can use any of the two above operators in your case. Note that `$inc` can be used with fields with numbers only.